# Upload de arquivo ao asp.net core pelo fetch

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou editando a pergunta anterior.

Esta `function` percorre uma tabela com `input file` e joga num `formData`
porém ao enviar por `fetch` ao `asp.net core` está chegando `null`

```
function uploadFiles() {


let inputFile;
let formData = new FormData();

jQuery('#tblDocumentosAnexos > tbody > tr').each(function () {
         inputFile = jQuery(this).find('td').eq(2).children()[0].files[0];
        formData.append("arquivos", inputFile, inputFile.name);
  });

console.log(formData);

fetch('upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
})}
```

**Método no asp.net core**

```
    [Route("upload")]
    [HttpPost]
    public void Upload(List<IFormFile> files)
    {

    }
```